# Fatal error: (in a class) Cannot redeclare replaceurl() (previously declared in www/link.php

Tags: php

I have a class that processed data and extract link, email and hashtag, the issue that I am having is when I called the class more than once, it gives the error `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare replaceurl() (previously declared in C:\wamp\www\ln.php:13)`

Here is the class

```
 class HtmlLinkUtility
    {
        public static $BaseDomain = null;
        public static function ReplaceEmailToHtmlLink($source)
        {
            return preg_replace('/([_.0-9a-z-]+@([0-9a-z][0-9a-z-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,3})/i',
                '<a href="mailto:\1">\1</a>', $source);
        }

        public static function ReplaceUrlToHtmlLink($source)
        {
            function replaceUrl($groups) {
                $url = $groups[1];
                return '<a href="' . $url . '"' . (strpos($url, HtmlLinkUtility::$BaseDomain) !== false ?
                    ' target="_blank"' : '') . '>' . $url . '</a>';
            }

            return preg_replace_callback('!(((f|ht){1}(tp://|tps)|(www.))[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_+.~#?&//=]+)!i',
                replaceUrl, $source);
        }
        public static function Htags($source){ 
        $regex = "/#+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/"; 
        $source = preg_replace($regex, '<a href="tag.php?tag=$1">$0</a>', $source); 
        return $source; 
        }

        public static function ReplaceTextDataToLinks($source, $baseDomain)
        {
            self::$BaseDomain = $baseDomain;
            return self::Htags(self::ReplaceUrlToHtmlLink(self::ReplaceEmailToHtmlLink($source)));
        }
    }

echo  HtmlLinkUtility::ReplaceTextDataToLinks("test@test.com<br />http://www.google.com/<br />http://www.test.com/ #madekir", "ivotism.com");
echo  HtmlLinkUtility::ReplaceTextDataToLinks("test@test.com<br />http://www.google.com/<br />http://www.test.com/ #madekir", "ivotism.com");
echo  HtmlLinkUtility::ReplaceTextDataToLinks("test@test.com<br />http://www.google.com/<br />http://www.test.com/ #madekir", "ivotism.com");
```

The first `echo` worked fine, the secondand the third will not, it produce the error above, please can someone help me out, whats wrong?

Comment: It doesn't matter that you're nesting your function definition inside a method, it's still simply a function definition that will be created in global scope, and every call to HtmlLinkUtility::ReplaceUrlToHtmlLink() will attempt to defined it again.... __don't nest function definitions__ and if you absolutely have to define functions within a function/method that you'll call multiple times, use an `if_defined()` test

Comment: U prolly wanted an anom function : just do preg_replace_callback($pattern, function() { // replace logic }, $subject);

Comment: Please what do you suggest? Whats the way out?

Comment: @DarkBee That is what replaceUrl() function returns or ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably wanted to use a anonymous function.
Switch your code up to this :

```
    public static function ReplaceUrlToHtmlLink($source)
    {

       return preg_replace_callback('!(((f|ht){1}(tp://|tps)|(www.))[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_+.~#?&//=]+)!i', function ($groups) {
            $url = $groups[1];
            return '<a href="' . $url . '"' . (strpos($url, HtmlLinkUtility::$BaseDomain) !== false ?' target="_blank"' : '') . '>' . $url . '</a>';
        }, $source);
    }
```

Comment: It doesnt seems to be working, but trying to figure out why it is not working

Comment: I got this error when i modified and run the code, `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in C:\wamp\www\ln.php on line 29`

Comment: @MandeKira [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) became available as of PHP5.3. You're running a lower version then. The link also shows an example, but I see u've managed to bypass it tho

Comment: You are right, I running on Version 5.2. , I run your code and its okay on Version 5.3. you deserved a plus!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I finally achieve it.

```
 public static function ReplaceUrlToHtmlLink($source)
        {
            if (!function_exists("replaceUrl")){
            function replaceUrl($groups) {
                $url = $groups[1];
                return '<a href="' . $url . '"' . (strpos($url, HtmlLinkUtility::$BaseDomain) !== false ?
                    ' target="_blank"' : '') . '>' . $url . '</a>';
            }
            }

            return preg_replace_callback('!(((f|ht){1}(tp://|tps)|(www.))[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_+.~#?&//=]+)!i',
                replaceUrl, $source);
        }
```